Past perfect with different time expressions

I had been cooking when she came

It's a good sentece showing that I started it before her arrival

I had been cooking by her arrival

Here, past perfect continuous doesn't make sense unless we add something like "for 3 hours"

I had been sleeping by the time she came

To me this sentence is fine and needs no changes. Did I get it right?


Suggests the cooking is finished, otherwise "I had started cooking when she came". 2. You don't like anyway. 3. Is not idiomatic, perhaps "I had slept before she came", or "I was asleep when she came".


@WeatherVane  so, we don't continuous tenses with "by the time" at all?

You can say "I was cooking by the time she came".

If you mean that you were asleep when she arrived, say "I was sleeping/asleep". "I had been sleeping" without a time span could mean that you had taken a nap earlier and then woken up.

I don't see that changing the verb from sleeping to cooking makes a difference, since "by her arrival" and "by the time she came" are essentially the same. So for 3 as well as 2, the perfect continuous doesn't make sense without a time span. You might say "I was sleeping by the time you came home," or "I had been sleeping for two hours by the time you came home. Though in both cases it might be a bit more idiomatic to use "be asleep": "I was already asleep by the time you came home," "I had been asleep for two hours by the time you came home."

why don't we need a time span for instance in this example " I had been playing when she arrived". How is it different? How can I know when I need the time span to justify perfect continuois and when it isn't necessary?

@Gregor I don't think that sentence is advisable. I'd use simple past. Unless I meant "I had [just] been playing [and had stopped recently,] when she arrived." In that case the context would help make this meaning clear. But note, "when she arrived" is different than "by the time she arrived." Not even this meaning would make sense with "by the time."

@Gregor It's like the difference between "I'll finish at noon" and "I'll finish by noon."
